# Было ли сочетание «на чеку» на оригинале плаката «Не болтай!»?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, наречия, история, старая-орфография

Если поискать изображение советского плаката "Не болтай", то в результатах будет множество его версий со следующим стихом (орфография сохранена):

> Будь **на чеку**,
> В такие дни
> Подслушивают стены.
> Недалеко от болтовни
> И сплетни
> До измены.

Является ли это следствием старой грамоты на плакате? Нет сомнения, что в оригинале все надписи на нём соответствовали нормам языка. Сейчас "на чеку" нормам [не соответствует](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83), при этом в интернете распространены варианты этого плаката с разными написаниями фразы, но неизменно наличие пробела. Или всё же это следствие перепечатки какого-то изначально неграмотного новодела? [image: Плакат "Не болтай"]

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, *Dmitry Ilukhin*! Подправьте, пожалуйста, текст цитаты. «Будь на чеку. / В такие дни / Подслушивают стены. / Недалеко от болтовни / И сплетни / До измены» (С. Я. Маршак).

Comment: Много различной информации по теме   http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1766076-otkuda-proizoshlo-vyrazhenie-byt-nacheku.html  Правило было утверждено в 1956 году §83  (основание: слово без НА не употребляется).

Comment: Плакат распространялся на западных рубежах в границах СССР того времени. Не так давно мне было попалась вся его предыстория. Ой о чем там только нет! И о "финской", и о именно Советском взятии Бреста (с его Крепостью) еще пред 40-м годом, и многое другое в том же духе. Разумеется, вопрос о шпионаже среди "новых" граждан страны у прибывшей на место службы администрации стоял очень остро. Да и плакат этот был "введен" именно сразу после Договора Молотова-Риббентропа. А сам тов. Маршак, будучи почти "придворным" и специально "нанятым" поэтом, многое перенимал у других знаменитостей. На одном из л

Comment: Вероятно, Ваше знание истории можно отнести к ляпсусам. Навскидку: плакат, конечно же, распространялся по *всей* территории Союза; пакт Молотова — Риббентропа был подписан в 1939 году, а плакат напечатан в 1941.

Answer (score 1):

Колебания в написании этого слова имеются и в словаре В. И. Даля (в разных статьях и в разных по времени изданиях).

[Чи́кать](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%A1%D0%942/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%94%D0%9E) (1882) — *Быть **на чику*** (ошибочно *на чеку*), совсѣмъ готовымъ, ожидая чего. *Волка стеречь, **начику́** сидѣть.*
[Очика́ться](https://books.google.ee/books?id=kt1bAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA3-PA1349&lpg=RA3-PA1349&dq=%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=YGV5K_bjg6&sig=ACfU3U1TDQMp3dd65C6Zm4SuQjUFB79cbQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNvpbCpbf1AhWTn4sKHTheA_EQ6AF6BAgYEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&f=false) (1865) — быть **на-чику**.
[**Начеку**](https://lexicography.online/explanatory/%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83) —  нареч. или вернее **начику**, не от чеки, а от чик: наготове, вготове, совсем. *Я заеду, будь начику. Не будь оплошен, а будь начику, во всякое время.*

В орфографическом словаре Д. Н. Ушакова (1938 года издания) слово отсутствует, а вот в словаре 1944 года уже имеется: [начеку́, *нареч.*](https://viewer.rusneb.ru/ru/000199_000009_005357147?page=58&rotate=0&theme=white) (Д. Н. Ушаков, С. Е. Крючков; разворот № 58). Плакат же был напечатан в 1941 году (редактор Е. Поволоцкая) с раздельным написанием наречия: *на чеку*.

Вполне возможно, что на выбор раздельного написания повлияла не устоявшаяся на то время орфография.
А может, автор так специально написал? И это окказионализм — уже от слова "чека"(война ведь!). У Маршака особых словечек было предостаточно.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса: [на чеку](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=2&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform)

Comment: Орфографический словарь  РАН: начеку. Этимология слова неясная, падежное управление в современном языке не прослеживается.  Уже давно бы следовало утвердить ситное написание.

Answer (score 0):

Надпись на плакате [подлинная](https://gallerix.ru/pic/_UNK/1973977528/1732069683.jpeg). Почему "начеку" тогда писали раздельно — не знаю, но ничуть не удивлён: надо помнить, что до 1956 гг. орфография была довольно-таки плавающей. В Нацкорпусе до 40-х годов включительно встречается и раздельное написание, и слитное, и дефисное: "на-чеку".

Answer (score 0):

~1. Нет никаких оснований считать что плакат -- не подлинный.

~2. Касательно происхождения и правописания. Шанский и Крылов дружно возводят слово не к какому-то далевскому "чику", а к исконно славянскому морфу "чек" (не смешивать с современным значением), с семантическим полем "стража", "охрана".

Ныне это значение утеряно, но, судя по всему, относительно недавно, что и повлияло на исторический выбор раздельного написания ("на чеку"). Наречия, образованные от существительных с помощью предлога, тяготеют по современным правилам к раздельному написанию, так было и раньше, хотя и с меньшей регулярностью.
Но вот когда порождающее слово не является существительным (т.е. без предлога не употребляется), то написание заведомо слитное. Видимо, в правилах-56 это учли.

Остается, правда, вопрос, совсем ли исчезло исходное значения слова "чек" из языка, или современное "чека" (предохранитель - у гранаты, например), имеющее некоторое семантическое родство со старославянским, имеет к нему и этимологическое отношение.
К сожалению, четкого ответа "навскидку" я не обнаружил, поскольку уверенной этимологии для слова "чека" не дает ни один из доступных мне авторитетных источников. Хотя такой вариант не исключен.